# How to sort words with custom chars (without the sort method/function)?

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I have a task in school, where i must order an array with these last names: `"Čop", "Dugonik" and "Caf"` by Slovenian alphabet. Without `"Čop"` it works with a simple `"bubble sort"`, but with `"Čop"` i can't make it work. I compare the chars by the ASCII table. The Slovenian alphabet goes: A, B, C, Č, D, ... Any ideas? It works when i sort it by ENG alphabet. I compare 2 last names with this function (+ 1 simple bubble sort function for sorting):

```
    static bool Uredi(Stranka stranka1, Stranka stranka2)
    {
        bool prviJeManjši = false;
        int dolžinaKrajšegaPriimka;

        // zagotovi da nebo prvi priimek daljši od drugega
        if (stranka1.priimek.Length > stranka2.priimek.Length)
        {
            dolžinaKrajšegaPriimka = stranka2.priimek.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            dolžinaKrajšegaPriimka = stranka1.priimek.Length;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dolžinaKrajšeBesede; i++)
        {
            if ((char)stranka1.priimek[i] < (char)stranka2.priimek[i])
            {
                prviJeManjši = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return prviJeManjši;
    }
```

Comment: You should completely separate your sorting algorithm from your comparer.  You should have a comparer who's sole responsibility is to be given two strings and to indicate which comes first.  The sorting algorithm can then be given that comparer and then be able to sort anything based on any criteria.

Comment: The default string comparison for me produces the results you say that it should.

Comment: Why are you comparing chars as ASCII rather than in their native format?

Comment: @tastro When I took the strings that you gave, and just used `string.CompareTo` it produced the correct result, by your own standards, so you shouldn't need to do a thing.

Comment: @tastro: Servy has already answered your question. .NET knows about strings. It knows about how to sort them too. Its quite good like that. Almost like somebody thought "Hey, maybe people will want to sort strings with this language one day".

Comment: @bradlarson Why did you roll back the last change?  It looks like you edited an answer back into the question.  The question shouldn't have an answer edited into it.

Comment: @Servy - Oops, wrong revision. Was trying to clean up after the rage-quit and was rolling all of them back to their old state. Should have gone a step earlier.

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement IComparer Interface or Comparison Delegate.
Here is the way to do so with lambda expression

```
        List<String> list = new List<string>() { "Čop", "Dugonik", "Caf" };
        string alphabet = "ABCČDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        list.Sort((s1,s2) =>
        {
            s1 = s1.ToUpper();
            s2 = s2.ToUpper();
            if (s1 != s2)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (s1[i] != s2[i])
                    {
                        int index1 = alphabet.IndexOf(s1[i]);
                        int index2 = alphabet.IndexOf(s2[i]);
                        if (index1 != index2)
                            return index1 - index2;
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        });
        list.ForEach(i =>  Console.WriteLine(i));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Of course you will need to modify the alphabet.. 

BTW, I want a piece of the grade as well :)

You can also change current culture to Slovanian

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sl-SI");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

Comment: Doing a `ToUpper` before sorting is generally not always a good idea. It might work in this case but in greek where they have a capital I with a dot and a lower case I without a dot you need to be careful about `ToUpper` because it might not do it to the right upper case letter.